# How to connect to the SQLite database password using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-4, navicat

my question is very similar to an already answered previously, the only diferncia is that I use Entity Framework.
I developed an application in C # and I use SQLite with Navicat and I need to protect my database password.
I was reviewing the answers given to questions related but do not serve me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: "connect to the SQLite database password" - yeah. Ever been eating a window? It makes no sense to connect to a password.

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the password in the provider connection string